# Progress tracking doesn't work in an UWP async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-core, uwp

I am trying to track the export progress on my UWP app. It should trigger a progress ring on my view. What Seems to be happening is that exporting logic occupies the same thread and after all the exporting is done, just then the setter of my WorkInProgress is called.

My View:

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="LibraryProgressRing"
Style="{StaticResource ProgressRingBase}"
IsActive="{x:Bind ViewModel.WorkInProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

My ViewModel method:

```
    private async void ExportItems(ExportType type)
    {
        var progress = new Progress<bool>();
        progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, workInProgress) => WorkInProgress = workInProgress;
        var model = SelectedNote.Model;
        await _exportService.ExportSingleAsync(model, type, progress);
    }
```

My export method:

```
public async Task ExportSingleAsync(MyModel model, ExportType exportType, IProgress<bool> progress)
        {
            var dto = new ModelDto()
            {   
                Id = model.Id,
                Ink = await _storageService.GetInkModel(model.Id),
                Language = model.LanguageName,
                Title = model.Title
            };

            var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add($"{exportType.GetFileType()}", new List<string> { exportType.GetFileExtension() });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = dto.Title;
            var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                progress.Report(true);

                switch (exportType)
                {
                    case ExportType.Txt:
                        var fileFormat = exportType.GetFileFormat();
                        var txt = await CreateTextFromApi(dto, fileFormat);
                        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, txt);

                        break;
                    case ExportType.Jpg:
                    case ExportType.Png:
                        var image = CreateLocalImage(dto);
                        await _storageService.StoreBitmapAsync(file, image);

                        break;
                    case ExportType.Svg:
                        var svg = await CreateImageFromApi(dto, exportType);
                        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, svg);

                        break;
                    case ExportType.Pdf:
                        var pdf = await CreatePdfFromApi("vector", dto);
                        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, pdf);

                        break;
                    case ExportType.Doc:
                        var doc = await CreateDocFromApi(dto);
                        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, doc);

                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException($"Single item export is not supported with {exportType.GetFileFormat()} file format.");
                }

                progress.Report(false);
            }
        }
```

Please tell me if I am correct in my assumption that this is a blocked thread issue and what might be causing it. It does successfully trigger the ProgressRing for parts of the second, so it's not a xaml/binding issue for sure. I need my WorkInProgress setter called right after progress.Report(true) is fired.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean when you called the progress.Report(true); method, the ProgressChanged event of progress was not triggered until the async method finished? When I tried to test it, the ProgressChanged event can be triggered after calling the progress.Report(true); method. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? In addition, if you directly set the model.WorkInProgress as true to replace the progress.Report(true) method, can it work?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT On the first question - yes. I have no access to WorkInProgress from the class where ExportSingleAsync is. It would work though, as I've tried it in ExportItems method. Problem is, I don't want the progress ring shown while the save window is open.

Comment: At first, I thought that the model you passed to the ExportSingleAsync method was the ViewModel, so you can directly access the WorkInProgress. I misunderstood. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? For the above code snippet, I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I'm very grateful for your assistance, but I think I solved my problem. You can expect an answer to the question from me in the upcomming minutes. Underlying code was too complex for sampling anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the underlying problem - a logic inside the CreateImageFromApi method was relying on the UIThread, so the whole method was executed synchronously there. We had to change the underlying logic and also write the following code for good measure:

```
        public async Task ExportSingleAsync(MyModel model, ExportType exportType, IProgress<bool> progress)
        {
            var dto = new ModelDto()
            {   
                Id = model.Id,
                Ink = await _storageService.GetInkModel(model.Id),
                Language = model.LanguageName,
                Title = model.Title
            };

            var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add($"{exportType.GetFileType()}", new List<string> { exportType.GetFileExtension() });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = dto.Title;
            var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                progress.Report(true);

                await Task.Run(() => ExportFilesAsync(exportType, notes, folder));

                progress.Report(false);
            }
        }
```

The switch is located inside ExportFilesAsync method. Task.Run forces the method to execute in a new thread. That frees up the UIThread to handle the ProgressChanged callback.